# how do i run command-line ant with stuff in the classpath?

Tags: ant

In eclipse, I can tell my external ant tool to run with stuff in the classpath.

If i want to run ant from the command line, how would i do that?

For argument's sake, the classpath i want to add is `c:\some\folder\here\hooray.jar`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `-lib` argument. From the Ant docs on [this page](http://ant.apache.org/manual/running.html):

> Additional directories to be searched may be added by using the -lib option. The -lib option specifies a search path. Any jars or classes in the directories of the path will be added to Ant's classloader.